Как нажать на кнопку для открытия Mini App в telethon, а после спарсить Mini App?
Мне нужно парсить Mini App, а как сымитировать хотя бы нажатие кнопки с помощью telethon я не нашёл.
Пример какую кнопку мне нужно открывать:

Мой код который получился:
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 'XXX'  # Ваш API ID
api_hash = 'XXX'  # Ваш API HASH

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash, system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users='@xrocket'))
async def handler(event):
    if event.message.buttons:
        print("Получено сообщение с кнопками:")
        for row in event.message.buttons:
            for button in row:
                if button.text == 'Пройти проверку':
                    print(button)

    else:
        print("Получено сообщение без кнопок.")


async def main():
    await client.start()
    print("Клиент запущен и отслеживает бот xrocket!")
    await client.run_until_disconnected()


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

